# Error while importing Formik type in formik v2

Tags: typescript, formik

I got a typescript problem while importing Formik when I updated formik from v1 to v2.

With v1 I used to use this code:

```js
import { Formik, FormikProps } from 'formik';
[...] 

export class Form<IFormValues> extends Component<IProps<IFormValues>> {
  private form: Formik<IFormValues> | null = null;

  public componentDidUpdate(prevProps: IProps<IFormValues>): void {
    const { props, form } = this;

    if (props.hasToReset && form) {
      form.handleReset();
      props.toggleFormReset(false);
    }
    if (form && props.formErrors && prevProps.formErrors !== props.formErrors) {
      form.setErrors(props.formErrors.fields);
    }
  }

  public render(): ReactNode {
    const { getInitialFormValues, getValidationSchema, onSubmit } = this.props;

    return (
      <Formik
        initialValues={getInitialFormValues()}
        enableReinitialize
        onSubmit={onSubmit}
        validationSchema={getValidationSchema()}
        render={this.renderForm}
        ref={(el: Formik<IFormValues> | null): void => {
          this.form = el;
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  public renderForm = (formikProps: FormikProps<IFormValues>): ReactNode => {
    const { renderMainForm, renderSubForm, inlineSubmitButton, renderBottomButtons } = this.props;

    return (
      <>
        <form onSubmit={formikProps.handleSubmit}>
          <Grid container>
              {renderMainForm(formikProps)}
              {renderBottomButtons(formikProps)}
          </Grid>
        </form>
        {!!renderSubForm && renderSubForm()}
      </>
    );
  };
}
```

But in v2, I got the Typescript Error: "Cannot find module 'Formik'" for both Formik used as types, (not for the component)

I checked the source file "formik/dist/Formik.d.ts"

in v1:
export declare class Formik...

in v2:
export declare function Formik...

I'm no Typescript expert, how could I fix this so that it works again ?

Thank you a lot for your help!

Comment: Formik is a React component, not an object type. What are you trying to do with ```private form: Formik<IFormValues> | null = null;```? You're declaring a class property that's a React component? Post your full component, that line should probably just be removed.

Comment: Actually `form` is also used as a component, I hope it will be clearer with the full component. I'm pretty sure I had seen this way of doing in a Medium article about Formik and Typescript (maybe one year ago) but I'm not able to find it anymore :( It was clear for me at this time...